# jQuery: Change the CSS class for all li icon expect the selected li icon

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I am using [Font Awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) in all `li` elements of `ul`

**Issue**

When user click the user icon I am changing the Icon's color black into yellow. if user click another icon it will be also in yellow color

How do I remove the already existed yellow icon. which means there will be only one yellow icon should be there. [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeysinghanbu/804jeg82/309/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="user-list">
    <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
     <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
     <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
     <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".user").click(function (e) {
                if ($(this).hasClass("yellow")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("yellow");
                    $(this).addClass("black");
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass("black");
                    $(this).addClass("yellow");
                }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `$(".user.yellow").not(this).removeClass()` before adding removing class from element:

```
  $(".user.yellow").not(this).removeClass();
```

also you can narrow down your code by using `.toggleClass()` insteading of checking and show/hide.

```
 var user = $(".user").click(function (e) {
   user.filter('.yellow').not(this).toggleClass('yellow black');
   $(this).toggleClass("yellow black");
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zc6tr3d3/)**

Comment: @JeysinghAnbu: check the fiddle

Comment: I checked the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxoveLqy/). When I click all icons and second time changing color is not working

Answer (score 0):

My own suggestion would be the following:

```
// binding the anonymous function of the click() method
// as the click event-handler:
$(".user").click(function (e) {

    // toggling between the named classes (if the element currently
    // has the class of 'black' it will be switched to 'yellow', and
    // vice-versa:
    $(this).toggleClass('black yellow')

        // switching to the siblings, selecting only those with the
        // class of 'yellow' and toggling those elements' class
        // to switch from 'yellow' class-name to 'black':
        .siblings('.yellow').toggleClass('yellow black');
});
```

```js
$(".user").click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('black yellow').siblings('.yellow').toggleClass('yellow black');
});
```

```css
@import url(http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
 #user-list {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
.black {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="user-list">
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/804jeg82/313/).

Further, to use plain JavaScript the following is also an option:

```
function highlightOnlyActive() {
    // the settings for the function:
    var s = {
        'activeClassName' : 'yellow',
        'inactiveClassName' : 'black'
    },

    // caching the 'this' variable for
    // use within other scopes:
        current = this;

    // Using Function.prototype.call() to allow the use of
    // Array.prototype.forEach() on the Array-like NodeList
    // returned by document.querySelectorAll(), allowing us
    // to iterate over the returned NodeList as an Array and
    // perform a function/action on each item returned:
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.parentNode.children, function (el) {

            // if the current Node ('el') is not the clicked-node
            // ('current'):
            if (el !== current) {

                // we unconditionally remove the 's.activeClassName'
                // and add the 's.inactiveClassName':
                el.classList.remove(s.activeClassName);
                el.classList.add(s.inactiveClassName);
            }
        });

    // here we simply toggle the 's.inactiveClassName' and
    // 's.activeClassName' classes:
    current.classList.toggle(s.activeClassName);
    current.classList.toggle(s.inactiveClassName);  
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#user-list li.user'), function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', highlightOnlyActive);
});
```

```js
function highlightOnlyActive() {
  var s = {
      'activeClassName': 'yellow',
      'inactiveClassName': 'black'
    },
    current = this;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.parentNode.children, function(el) {
    if (el !== current) {
      el.classList.remove(s.activeClassName);
      el.classList.add(s.inactiveClassName);
    }
  });

  current.classList.toggle(s.activeClassName);
  current.classList.toggle(s.inactiveClassName);
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#user-list li.user'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', highlightOnlyActive);
});
```

```css
@import url(http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
 #user-list {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}
.black {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="user-list">
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
  <li class='black user'><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/804jeg82/312/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).